# $T:V\to W$, both has same basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $W,V$ have the same basis $\{u_1,u_2\}$ and that $T:V \to W$ is a linear transformation. Give an example (not the identity transformation) of

a) $T = T^{-1}$
b) $T= T^2$

for a) $T=T^{-1} \Rightarrow A=A^{-1}$
let $A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right]$

$A=A^{-1} \Rightarrow A^2=I$ $A^2 =  \left[\begin{array}{cc}a^2+bc&ba+bd\\ca+cd&d^2+bc\end{array}\right] =  \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]$

$a^2+bc-bc-d^2=1-1 = a^2 - d^2 = (a-d)(a+d)=0\\c(a+d)=0\\b(a+d)=0$

From here though I'm a tad iffy, like $ \left[\begin{array}{cc}2&3\\0&-2\end{array}\right]$ would satisfy what I got solving the system but $A \neq A^{-1}$ but if I do $ \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&3\\0&-1\end{array}\right]$
$A =A^{-1}$ and $A^2=I$

I'll do (b) after I get this one.

thanks!

Comment: Since you only need ONE example, you might want to look at $c = d = 0 $. Also, what exactly is your question?

Comment: You've lost one equation! You can't simply take the difference of $a^2+bc=1$ and $d^2+bc=1$, you need also to keep one of them. In fact, $a=2$, $b=3$ and $c=0$ does not satisfy $a^2+bc=1$.

Comment: You need only look at diagonal matrices to find suitable examples.

Comment: c=d=0 is a singular matrix. 
My question is whether I went about it correctly which a gather I didn't because I' m not getting concrete examples based on my solved system

Comment: it seems as long as $a = \pm 1$, $d=-a$ and either c,b both equal 0, or at least one does it'll work but the way I solved the system doesn't exactly make that clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good practice to work through these exercise using the nitty-gritty algebra, but these questions are also a good opportunity to develop geometric intuition.

In particular, you've probably seen that three important geometric operations are linear transformations:

1. Rotations about the origin $T=\left[\begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{array}\right]$;
2. Projection onto the line spanned by the vector $v$: $T=\frac{vv^T}{\|v\|^2}$;
3. Reflection about the line perpendicular to the vector $n$: $I - 2\frac{nn^T}{\|n\|^2}$.

Now part a) is asking for a transform that is the same as its inverse, i.e. when applied twice gives you the identity. And part b) is asking for a transformation that does the same thing when applied twice as when applied once, in other words, after applying it once, applying it a second time doesn't do anything additional. Examples of both of these can be readily found by thinking about the above geometric transformations.